# I create a web service, GET is working fine, But POST is not

Tags: c#, .net, post

I have created a Webservice in C#. I have encountered:

**1- GET is working fine and returns 200 for:**

(a) localhost - localhost

(b) PC - Remote Server

**2- POST is working fine and returns 200 for:**

(a) localhost - localhost (JQuery AJAX)

**3- POST returns 500 (Internal Server Error) for:**

(a) POSTMAN (localhost - localhost)

(b) POSTMAN (PC - Remote Server)

**Interface**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    [OperationContract]
    [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

    string getable(string value);

    [OperationContract]
    [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string postable(string value);
}
```

**Webservice**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public string getable(string value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}" , value);
    }

    public string postable(string value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}
```

**Web.config (Image)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JYw9.png)

---

### Edited

**VS Output log**

Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Request","time":"2018-02-15T11:26:57.6572654Z","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"web: 2.0.0.25000","ai.device.roleInstance":"xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.com.my","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.operation.name":"POST /Service1.svc/postable","ai.operation.id":"Uo2rSVl2OFQ="},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"Uo2rSVl2OFQ=","name":"POST /Service1.svc/postable","startTime":"2018-02-15T19:26:57.6572654+08:00","duration":"00:00:00.0279599","success":false,"responseCode":"500","url":"http://localhost:60121/Service1.svc/postable","httpMethod":"POST","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}

**In POSTMAN**

Method: POST

URL: http://localhost:60121/Service1.svc/postable

Header: Content-Type , application/json

Body: value,anystring

**Returns:**

{
    "ExceptionDetail": null,
    "ExceptionType": null,
    "Message": "The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.",
    "StackTrace": null
}

Comment: HTTP 500 indicates an unhandled exception: what error handling do you have in place (if none: add some). Use this to get the details of the exception.

Comment: (After question edit) You have been told one way to see the details of the exception: follow them.

Comment: Can you suggest where can I put the error handler. You mean try and catch? I tried with POSTMAN, it does not even hit any line of the POST method in C#

Comment: You don't need a try/catch in the code, look at either event logs on the server (if the app logs them) or use Visual Studio debugger

Comment: Interesting you note that POST works fine with used via jQuery, but not PostMan. That would suggest that perhaps you constructed your request incorrectly when using PostMan

Comment: Richard, as you can see in web.config, I have already set IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults  as true.

Comment: ADyson, I have edited the question.

Comment: Check [500 Internal Server Error](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-troubleshoot-common-http-error-codes).

Comment: In your Body from Postman: "value,anystring" doesn't look like JSON to me

Comment: ADyson, it is not a code, it is just the information I gave. It means, I put in POSTMAN, the key as 'value', and value as 'anyString'. The generated code for JSON would be: {value:anystring}, depends on what kind of format you want to generate in POSTMAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for my problem. I just stop using WCF Webservice.

I started using MVC Web API, and it is working fine. It is even more easier to use.

You can find the tutorial here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

And for POST, you can follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eGUix3Nkjg (Direct see the code in minute 8:39)